# Is this wiring dangerous? Smart Thermostat C-wire AC adapter twisted together

Tags: hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

Is this wiring scenario dangerous? Is it likely produce sparks or damage my HVAC system?

Please read the description and see the image below.

**Description**

I didn't have a C-wire for my Emerson Sensi smart thermostat so I got an AC adapter. The adapter has two wires. Instructions say to put one of them in the C slot and the other into either RC or RH.

However my system (gas furnace and central AC) requires both the Blue RC and the Red RH wire to function properly. I tried putting the second wire into Y2 and W2 to see if that would work, no luck.

The working combination was to place one wire into the C slot as seen below, and the second one I twisted together with the RH wire. Works well so far.

Let me know if you think this could be a problem, and what else I might try to fix this.

From my reading, it seems like I could probably add a C-wire without this silly AC adapter, but it's an apartment with a cramped furnace closet and I would like to avoid running new cables through the wall.

[image: .]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Sounds OK to me, but let's see if one of our pros has more to say. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Could you share the document that advises you to use an AC adapter?

Comment: @jhw20 

No official document. That's just the general recommendation out there if you google "install smart thermostat no c-wire" 

For example from:  https://smartthermostatguide.com/what-if-i-dont-have-a-c-wire/

_This thermostat is hooked up only to heat in a low voltage system. The addition of a fourth wire, either with an adapter or new wires, could act as the C-wire if properly wired to the furnace._

Comment: @jwh20 this is the exact adapter I'm using. It's a hack for sure

https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07HRK7CWX?pf_rd_r=QNKEFGWE6VVAGC15KS1K&pf_rd_p=edaba0ee-c2fe-4124-9f5d-b31d6b1bfbee

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the furnace/air handler ends of the picture?  Also, are you OK with changing things out for a different way of making a C wire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are using low voltage infact finger safe voltages unless your adapter was a welder in a previous use I would not be concerned if everything is working, I have used adapters to power thermostats when it was cheaper than pulling new wire when RH & RC and fan were all good with my adapter (or transformer).

Comment: Great! thanks for this info

Comment: If you find answers or comments helpful upvote or accept green check mark that will help others find information with a similar question.